# CVTTSD2SI - a truncating instruction - uses rounding with "inexact" results?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, floating-point-conversion

According to the Intel documentation the instruction `CVTTSD2SI`, which truncates a fp-value to a 64 bit signed integer, rounds according to the MXCSR rounding-mode if the conversion is inexact.

But how can a simple *truncating* conversion be inexact? I think that either the value fits into the range of the integer or not; if not, there's no rounding but the value is -1 << 63 and an exception may be raised.

Here's what the [Intel doc says](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvttsd2si):

> *When a conversion is inexact, the value returned is rounded according to the rounding control bits in the MXCSR register.*

Answer (score 8):

An FP->integer conversion is inexact when the FP value was not already an integer.  e.g. 1.25 converts to integer `1` with a rounding error of 0.25.  But `1.0` converts *exactly* to `1`.  This is the same FP exception flag that would be raised by `1.0 / 3.0` with `divsd`, but not by `1.0 / 2.0`, because 0.5 is exactly representable as a float or double.

**That sentence is an error in the manual**.  CVTTSD2SI always uses truncation when the conversion is inexact, not the current rounding mode in MXCSR (which defaults to nearest, tie-break to even)

The exact same single-sentence paragraph is present in the [CVTSD2SI manual entry](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cvtsd2si), which *does* use MXCSR, so this is a copy/paste error by Intel.

---

#### Out-of-range is a different condition

> if not there's no rounding but the value is -1 << 63 and an exception may be raised.

That's a separate kind of exception from inexact.  The `cvttsd2si` manual covers this with

> If a converted result exceeds the range limits of signed doubleword integer ([with a 32-bit destination]), the **floating-point invalid exception** is raised, and if this exception is masked, the indefinite integer value (80000000H) is returned.

Similarly for 64-bit operand-size, the indefinite value is MSB set, other bits zero.  That same bit-pattern is used whether the FP value was positive or negative.

(It can of course also be a result of valid conversions, since the most-negative 2's complement number is a power of 2 and thus exactly representable as a double or even float.  A better choice might have been some large-magnitude by odd number, like `80000001h`, although that can still be the result of a valid double->int32 conversion.  But not float->int32 or (for a wider 64-bit version) double->int64.)

Check Intel's manuals for the full set of flags in MXCSR.  Or some article about that specifically, such as [https://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/simd/sse.php](https://softpixel.com/%7Ecwright/programming/simd/sse.php)

IE (Invalid-operation Exception) is a separate flag from FP overflow (OE) or underflow (UE).

---

#### Experimental test

Just to make sure, I tested with GDB `display $mxcsr` to show (and decode) MXCSR after every single-step.  (On an i7-6700k Skylake, but this behaviour is required so other CPUs should behave identically.)

```
section .rodata
frac: dq 1.75
whole: dq 2.0

section .text
global _start
_start:
  stmxcsr [rsp-8]                   ; in the red zone; x86-64 SysV
  cvtsd2si  eax, [frac]
  ldmxcsr [rsp-8]
  cvttsd2si edx, [frac]

  ldmxcsr [rsp-8]
  cvttsd2si ecx, [whole]
 ;... fall off the end because I only want to single-step this, and can exit GDB before letting it step past here
```

```
$ nasm -felf64 foo.asm && ld -o foo  foo.o 
$ gdb ./foo
(gdb) layout reg
 # and with recent GDB, layout n  to get regs + disassembly
(gdb) starti
(gdb) display $mxcsr
1: $mxcsr = [ IM DM ZM OM UM PM ]     
      # bunch of things masked, no raised exceptions
(gdb) si   a couple times
 # after <_start+5>     cvtsd2si eax,QWORD PTR [rip+0xff3]        # 0x402000
1: $mxcsr = [ PE IM DM ZM OM UM PM ]
         # PE = precision exception = inexact, plus the earlier mask flags
...
```

Each `ldmxcsr` reloads a no-exceptions-raised state so we can see what the next instruction did.

- `cvtsd2si` and `cvttsd2si` both set PE, the inexact exception flag, when converting 1.75 to integer.
- Both leave it clear when converting 2.0 to integer.

I didn't *unmask* any of the exceptions because I just wanted them recorded in the MXCSR sticky bits, not to trap and get a SIGFPE.